# LinkedIn API Ad Creatives Not Returning 'Document Ads'

Tags: linkedin-api

Hey I am making a request to the Linkedin API:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/creatives/urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCreative%3A{creativeid}
```

To try and get a specific creative back and it seems that the Linkedin API is not returning any creatives that have an Ad Type of "Document Ad".

Anyone have this issue?
All the other creatives return except the ones that are document ads.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a reply from support and this is expected - Native Documents/Document Ads are not apart of the API yet.